# Remove Network Settings indicator/app on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, network-manager

On my laptop (HP Envy 14, Core i5 with Intel 6200N wifi) the built in network manager/network settings applet or indicator or whatever is completely useless and just fails to connect to anything. I found a suggestion here to try using wicd instead, and it does work for me. I'd like to remove the default indicator if it's going to keep causing problems but it looks like I don't have network-manager or network-manager-gnome installed. How can I remove it?

(as a side note, is it possible that it wasn't working because network-manager wasn't installed? But it shows up and sometimes shows networks, it just fails to connect to them, and when I click anything in the settings it just turns off the wifi device altogether).

Answer (score 1):

You need to either Network Manager or WICD, not both.

For Network Manager:

- Install network-manager and network-manager-gnome.
- Deinstall wicd.
- Reboot.

For WICD:

- Install wicd.
- Deinstall network-manager and network-manager-gnome.
- Reboot.

Try the network manager first, to see if it solves your problem. If not, install WICD.

Comment: As my post says, I installed wicd which fixed my problem, but I apparently didn't have network-manager in the first place but I don't understand how that could be the case because very occasionally it would work and connect.